# Lubuntu 15.04 32 bit does not boot automatically - black screen, or ASCII boot process

Tags: boot, lubuntu, 15.04

I am unable to boot smoothly into a clean install of Lubuntu 15.04 32-bit, updated to the latest available releases.

Just after the motherboard finishes its thing and the PC proceeds towards boot, a blue Lubuntu logo shows up on the screen, but so briefly that I am not sure if I am imagining it. Promptly after that the screen goes black, and the monitor goes to standby. The system then (effectively) halts as after 2-3 minutes there are no signs of any progress.

I am then forced to do a hard reboot, which lands me into a static GRUB boot screen (does not autmatically progress to boot). I am here able to select `Ubuntu` and the boot proceeds and completes, but it does not look pretty - the boot progress graphic is just ASCII art and is offset to the top left of the screen. Nevertheless, it boots.

So, what I would like to know is:

1. What is causing a clean install of Lubuntu 15.04 32 bit to fail
   to boot?
2. How do I fix/disable whatever is causing it to fail to boot? Is
   there a way to force Lubuntu into Grub, but have the Grub
   automatically progress to full boot?

Answer (score 1):

I installed the nVidia driver and that seems to have fixed the "will not boot" issue.

Thus: install the proprietary driver for your graphics card as it may be related to the startup process hanging/dying when it hits the graphics subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar issue.
What I did to fix it was press on escape (several times) once the screen goes into standby.

Not 100% sure if it'll work for you but it's worth a try right :)